# ¿Cómo puedo poner una condición en un metodo each/map en ruby?

Tags: ruby, map, each

estoy intentando hacer una array en Ruby, y que si un elemento es mayor a 5, se le sume 2; pero no logro hacerlo, he intentado esto:

```
array = Array(1..10).map { |i| if i > 5 then i += 2 end }
p array
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código funciona correctamente, es decir, cuanto el elemento (`i`) es mayor que `5`, a este se le suman `2`; pero regresa `nil` cuando la condición no se cumple:

```
Array(1..10).map { |i| if i > 5 then i += 2 end }
#=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Para que regrese el valor del `i` cuando la condición no se cumpla, debes especificarlo; por ejemplo:

```
Array(1..10).map { |i| i > 5 ? i += 2 : i }
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

En este último ejemplo estoy utilizando un operador ternario, que es una versión corta de `if ... else ... end`.

---

Adicionalmente, podrías omitir `Array` y ejecutar `map` directamente sobre el rango (i.e. `1..10`):

```
(1..10).map { |i| i > 5 ? i += 2 : i }
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```